# Is Nil-Coalescing always needed when using firstIndex(of: Character) in Swift?

Tags: swift, string

Excerpt from *The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4.2)* documentation by Apple.

```
let greeting = "Hello, world!"
let index = greeting.firstIndex(of: ",") ?? greeting.endIndex

let beginning = greeting[..<index]
```

The above example works totally fine except after I exclude the Nil-coalescing part of the code.

```
let beginning = greeting[..<greeting.firstIndex(of: ",")]
```

By leaving out the `?? greeting.endIndex`, Xcode returns an error.

The question is why is it necessary?
Why can't we just use `firstIndex()` directly to access the substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example.

```
let greeting = "Hey There!"
let index = greeting.firstIndex(of: ",")
```

`index` is of type `Index?`, so it can be nil. Since the string has no ',', the value of index is nil.

So this code becomes illegal. Since index cannot be an optional value.

```
let beginning = greeting[..<index]
```

You can alternatively unwrap it and get the index if it is valid index like this.

```
guard let indexFound = index else {
    print("Character not) found in string"
    return
}

let beginning = greeting[..<indexFound]
print("The first occurance of the character is at \(beginning).")
```

> Real world example: (I know it's not good, but it should be enough :x)
>
> Remember the bot captcha's that pop up in websites? The ones that ask
>   you to identify the number of cars, street signs etc. So there you
>   click on the boxes which show the requirement. and click 'submit'. But
>   if there aren't any, you click 'Skip'. So drawing parallels. If you
>   have a valid index, it returns the valid index, otherwise it return
>   `nil` which is not an valid `Index`, but it is a valid answer to the
>   question asked. (Is there a ',' inside the string?) The problem here is, the next part. Slicing an array requires you to have a valid `Index`, so your `index` currently is an optional which you can change to a valid index by safely unwrapping like my example or having a nil-coalescing check at the time of getting the index.

You should look up optionals in Swift to get a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This example is way beyond my understanding of the language since I am a beginner but it won't hurt.

Comment: @Slick I have edited my answer which should help you understand the problem better. :)

Comment: Thanks! I have learned optional. The updated answer does make a lot of sense.

Comment: Once you have learnt what an optional optional, you can check how to safely unwrap optionals with `guard` and `if let`. Also it is not always necessary to have nil-coalescing done. You can have the variable as an optional because sometimes you handle the `nil` case along with the valid cases.

Answer (score 3):

As it may be no index for the supplied character , so following your way the app will crash

```
 func firstIndex(of element: Character) -> String.Index?
```

The optional return `String.Index?`  solves it  , and that's why you  need ??

if you don't supply ??

Then you have to force unwrap `let beginning = greeting[..<index]`  here index should be `index!` which will cause a crash if it's nil

Comment: The index is clearly an optional, so it can return `nil` which i think it does?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri yes this is the reason

Comment: Yes, i am saying that it is a valid response. Why should it throw an error? It can just return `nil` ? Why is the `?? greeting.endIndex` mandatory like he says?

Comment: Ok my bad. The error is returned at the next line. _whoops_ that makes sense.